# jQuery fails to remove parent div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying remove parent div when AJAX PHP Script is finished. Problem is that you when php Script is jQuery fails to remove div.

Does someone knows where's error in my code and why I can't remove wanted DIV with methods that I provided?

Here is code:

HTML:

```
<div id="newTask">  
<input type="hidden" id="taskID" 1="" name="taskID" value="39">
<input type="text" id="taskName1" name="taskName1" value="12">  
<span class="remove" onclick="removeDIVS(39);"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 function removeDIVS(currentID){

    $.ajax({
      url: 'scripts/removeTask.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: 'id='+currentID,

      success: function(data, status) {
        if(data == "OK") {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }
        else{
                  $('#TaskResult').html(data);
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    }); // end ajax call
  }
```

Comment: $(this).parent().remove(); - $(this) is not the span element as you probably expect

Comment: `this` refers to the `window`.

Comment: Probably because `$(this)` doesnt reference the div you want. Replace `$(this).parent().remove()` with `$("#newTask).remove()` to confirm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

HTML:

```
<div id="newTask">  
<input type="hidden" id="taskID" 1="" name="taskID" value="39">
<input type="text" id="taskName1" name="taskName1" value="12">  
<span class="remove" data-myid="39"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
var currentID = $(this).data('myid');
var parenID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
 $.ajax({
      url: 'scripts/removeTask.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: 'id='+currentID,

      success: function(data, status) {
        if(data == "OK") {
            $("#"+parenID).remove();
        }
        else{
                  $('#TaskResult').html(data);
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    }); // end ajax call
})
```

Comment: This is a better answer as it handles multiple instances and moves the javascript out of the markup. BTW you could just store `var parent = $(this).parent();`, then `parent.remove()`, so you aren't relying on it having an id (and apparently in this case, it being unique)

Comment: @jureispro you may need to put it in document.ready - just wrap the whole thing in `$(function() { ...code... });`

Comment: @jureispro - are you sure you are clicking on the SPAN? it is empty, you may add some content inside to be sure to click on it

Comment: @GRSEV .remove class got background-image

Comment: Should work, here is working example (without the AJAX part): http://jsfiddle.net/0p4593yy/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("#newTask").remove();
```

instead of

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

because here `$(this)` is not what you are expecting.

Comment: it will remove first row od newTask element. Problem is that I could have multiple newTask DIV elements and with your code

Comment: If they are multiple how come they all have ids, then it should have classes, id is not used for multiple elements.

Comment: @jureispro IDs must be unique on document context so if OP is using mutliple duplicate IDs, he has other issues coming

Comment: @A.Wolff they have unique ID because I am looping over results (with differnet counter) from Database to get all Tasks

Comment: @jureispro Wait, i didn't see you were OP ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff xD . I take care of that. I didnt want to show 50 of div id="newTask"